# Print strings of length of k from a and b

Tags: c

I want to write a programm, which can print all possible strings of length k that can be formed from a and b.

Example for k = 3: aaa, baa, aba, bba, aab, bab, abb, bbb.

My code isn't working. Can somebody please correct me? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abcombirec(char prefix[], int k) {
    char ab[] = {'a', 'b'};
    if (k == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", prefix);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        newprefix = prefix + ab[i];
        abcombirec(newprefix, k - 1);
    }
}

void abcombi(int k) {
    char str[] = "";
    abcombirec(str, k);
}

int main() {
    (abcombi(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The string concadation operator (`+`) does not work in C! You have to know the length when declaring it and use something like `strcat`

Comment: `s/does not work/does not exist/`

Comment: I remember on literally day one of my first job, I asked my team "what's the string concatenation operator in C?" and everybody just laughed. Never forget. :D

Comment: "_My code isn't working._" Why not? What does it do? What is that wrong?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Your code assumes that C "understands" operator `+` plus as a concatenation:

```
newprefix = prefix + ab[i];
```

However, that is not what is happening: C understands this expression as *pointer arithmetic*, interpreting `ab[i]` as an integer offset.

Concatenating a character to a string in C requires considerable amount of code:

- Allocate a buffer of sufficient length
- Copy the prefix into the buffer
- Add the desired character to the end
- Null-terminate the result

Here is how this looks in code:

```
size_t len = strlen(prefix);
char tmp[len+2];
strcpy(tmp, prefix);
tmp[len] = ab[i];
tmp[len+1] = '\0';
```

The rest of your code is fine; with this one change in place, your code produces the results that you expected ([demo](https://ideone.com/nJrQML)).

**Note:** this code allocates `tmp` in automatic memory. Considering what the code does, `k` would be pretty small (otherwise the code would run for a really long time) so array allocations in automatic memory wouldn't be a problem. However, you need to be very careful with this approach, because you can easily cause undefined behavior if `len` is too large. You should use more secure version of `strlen` and go for dynamic memory allocation in any scenario that goes into production.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick-n-dirty recursive function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void showboth(char* txt, int pos)
{
    if (pos == strlen(txt)-1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", txt);
        txt[pos] = 'b';
        printf("%s\n", txt);
        txt[pos]='a';
    }
    else
    {
        showboth(txt, pos+1);
        txt[pos] = 'b';
        showboth(txt, pos+1);
        txt[pos] = 'a';
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char text[5] = "aaa";

    showboth(text, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

### Example Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4256KB
aaa
aab
aba
abb
baa
bab
bba
bbb
```

Comment: This is an alternative code but you don't tell the OP what's wrong.